# tinymce: replace <img> tags on submit

Tags: tinymce

Don't know if this is possible.

I'm using tinymce as a text editor and I want to allow user insert images. I achieved this, and tinymce inserts a  tag with the proper src attribute.

The problem will come if later, I decide to change the path of the image or change its name, the text will still point to old location.

So I was wondering if tinymce can be configured to instead of generating a  tag generate some kind of mark (as the )  so would let me relate it to a register in database and replace it by a tag image in server side.

This is easy too, what is not easy is to have both solutions running simultaneously: show the user the  tag (while he/she is editing) but submiting to the server the "mark". Would tinymce support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this exactly answers your question but you can set a [callback on submit function in TinyMCE](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aTurn_tinyMCE_into_an_Ajax_editor) (usually used to make Tiny an AJAX editor) But you could grab the data with the callback and modify it

Answer (score 0):

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    valid_elements : '*[*]'
})
```

Use valid_elements field in configuration to allow tags.You can use specific tag too. Currently every tags are allowed in above configuration.